# How to apply normalization to images in testing phase when using keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to predict a new image using trained model. My accuracy is 95%. But the predict_classes always return the first label [0] whatever I input. 
I guess one of the reason is I use `featurewise_center=True` and `samplewise_center=True` in `ImageDataGenerator`. I think I should do the same thing on my input image. But I can't find what did these function do to the image.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

`ImageDataGenerator` code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
samplewise_center=True,
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=30,
zoom_range=30,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
samplewise_center=True,
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=30,
zoom_range=30,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
```

Prediction code (I use 100*100*3 image to train the model):

```
model = load_model('CNN_model.h5')
img = cv2.imread('train/defect/6.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,100,100,3])
img = img/255.

classes = model.predict_classes(img)

print (classes)
```

updated 11/14:

I change my code to predict image like below. But the model still predict the same class even if I feed the image which I have used to train my model(and got 95% accuarcy). Is there anything I missed?

```
model = load_model('CNN_model.h5')
img = cv2.imread('train/defect/6.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,100,100,3])
img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float64) 
img = train_datagen.standardize(img)

classes = model.predict_classes(img)
print(classes)
```

Comment: Maybe you could access the `featurewise_center` and `samplewise_center` attributes of a generator and apply them to the images?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `standardize()` method of `ImageDataGenerator` instance. From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#standardize):

> ### standardize
>
> ```
> standardize(x)
> ```
>
> Applies the normalization configuration to a batch of inputs.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - x: Batch of inputs to be normalized.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The inputs, normalized.

So it would be like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('train/defect/6.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,100,100,3])
img = train_datagen.standardize(img)

classes = model.predict_classes(img)
```

Note that it would apply the rescaling as well so there is no need to do it yourself (i.e. remove `img = img/255.`).

Further, keep in mind that since you have set `featurewise_ceneter=True` you need to use [`fit()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#fit) method of generator before using it for training:

```
train_datagen.fit(training_data)

# then use fit_generator method
model.fit_generator(train_datagen, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I remove featurewise ceneter to make my code easier, but the problem still exist. I revise my code in my question. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: @Gamuza What if you predict on all of your training data? Do you get 95% accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the problem that you used `cv2` to import your images, because when you use `cv2.imread`, the channels are not "r,g,b" but "b,g,r".

for example,

```
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

bgr = cv2.imread('r.jpg')
rgb = np.array(image.load_img('r.jpg'))
print(bgr[1,1,:],rgb[1,1,:])
```

result:

```
[ 83 113   0] [  0 114  83]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but some information:

From [this link](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) that is referenced in keras docs:

```
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')
```

I think you should do this way for training. Then for test I think using `train_datagen.standardize` is true.